# Erro 1005 : MySQL - não cria chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, mariadb

estou com um problema no MariaDB.

Eu criei duas tabelas `tbl_estoque` e `tbl_adiciona`.

Basicamente, eu não quero adicionar dados diretamente na `tbl_estoque`. Quero que por meio de uma `trigger`, ele verifique se o ultimo registro da `tbl_adiciona` existe na `tbl_estoque`. Se existir, ela apenas atualiza a quantidade em estoque, caso contrario, ela adiciona o registro na `tbl_estoque`.

Para fazer isso eu encontro dois problemas.

O primeiro problema é que basicamente eu não consigo adicionar um valor no `cod_produto` da `tbl_adiciona` que não esteja registrado na `tbl_estoque`.

Ele altera normalmente os registros existentes, mas não cria um novo.

Uma maneira que eu usei para tentar driblar esse problema, seria invertendo as chaves (colocando a chave estrangeira na `tbl_estoque`. Eis que eu me deparei com um segundo problema: não pode haver duplicidade de chaves estrangeiras, o que me impossibilita de inserir valores repetidos na `tbl_adiciona` (que a princípio foi designada apenas para isso).

O erro que aparece é o 1005 :

> **Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'teste'.'#sql-1218_5' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**

Relação das tabelas :

```
create table tbl_estoque(
cod_estoque int not null primary key auto_increment,
cod_produto int not null unique,
nome_produto varchar(50) not null, 
quantidade int not null
);

create table tbl_adiciona(
cod_adiciona int not null primary key auto_increment,
cod_produto int not null,
nome_produto varchar(50),
quantidade int not null
);

alter table tbl_estoque add constraint fk_codProduto foreign key(cod_produto) references tbl_adiciona (cod_produto);
```

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Você tentou fazer a tal trigger e não deu certo? Essa ideia de inverter a chave estrangeira não tem o menor sentido, a chave estrangeira tem que refletir o seu modelo de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se a tabela foi criada com a engine `InnoDB`, as vezes pode estar com uma engine que não permite a criação de FK.
Caso queira testar, de um `drop table tbl_estoque; drop table tbl_adiciona` e execute as seguintes instruções. Estou acrescentando a engine no final da instrução apenas, após isso, tente criar a FK novamente.

```
create table tbl_estoque(
cod_estoque int not null primary key auto_increment,
cod_produto int not null unique,
nome_produto varchar(50) not null, 
quantidade int not null
)Engine=InnoDB;

create table tbl_adiciona(
cod_adiciona int not null primary key auto_increment,
cod_produto int not null,
nome_produto varchar(50),
quantidade int not null
)Engine=InnoDB;
```